# wicket_pdf produces Error: PDF could not be generated

Tags: wicked-pdf

I am deploying a RoR app to our production environment.

```
App 9676 stdout:   Rendered users/check.pdf.erb (15.9ms)
App 9676 stdout: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 178ms
App 9676 stdout: 
App 9676 stdout: RuntimeError (Error: Failed to execute:
App 9676 stdout: ["/home/deploy/.bundler/customerportalapp/ruby/2.1.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.3/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q", "file:///tmp/wicked_pdf20140827-9676-6sbtcf.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20140827-9676-1qunpjr.pdf"]
App 9676 stdout: Error: PDF could not be generated!
App 9676 stdout:  Command Error: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `materialize': 
Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I think the error "Could not find rake-10.3.2" is a red herring. Rake 10.3.2 is installed.

I am at a loss as to where to start troubleshooting the error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with wkhtmltopdf, where bundler couldn't find rake even though it was installed.  I tried debugging this for a full day and gave up trying to find and fix the cause.

This workaround is the only thing that made it work for me.

`bundle --deployment`

It will bundle your gems in a .bundle folder in your app, making them reliably accessible to bundler.